# Magento2 | Reduce JS files to optimize site performance

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs, pagespeed

I am trying to figure out how I can exclude some js files that Magento2 loads and makes it so heavy however without compromising the functionality of the site.

On my site with Magento2 I have a lot of js resources as well as third-party js resources.
My question is: How can I exclude all the js files that Magento2 loads with require? If not, is it possible to be able to do it in another way for Magento2 to have high performance?

Any suggestions or advice I would very much welcome.

Translated with DeepL.com (free version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into Magepack. Its a very nice tool and free as well.

https://github.com/magesuite/magepack

Comment: Really interesting extension. I will take a look at them as soon as possible. Thanks for the reply ;)